# self-adjoint / orthonormal basis of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

Let $T$ be a linear operator on  a finite dimensional real inner product space $V$.Then $T$ is self-adjoint iff there exists an orthonormal $\beta$ for $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$.

Please provide the proof of this theorem.

Comment: I have a wonderful proof for this theorem, which is too big to fit in this comment section. I guess you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: @K.Power:I've proved first part of the theorem by using the statement of Schur's theorem,but getting stuck in the converse part.But,i'm not really sure what i've done is correct.

Comment: @PK Styles Ha, if you have already tried something, you'll get a better response if you provide some evidence of your own efforts.

Comment: This is not a site to get people to do your homework for you. People will help you with your homework by giving you hints and showing you where you've gone wrong if you give evidence that you have tried the problem and specify where you get lost.

Comment: @K.Power I dare say this was not part of any "homework"..OP is likely inquisitive and looking for the proof of a lemma that was given as such without being provided one.

Comment: @Ed_4434:Suppose T is self-adjoint,then the characteristic polynomial of T splits,then by Schur's theorem there exists an orthonormal basis $\ beta$ for V such that the matrix [T]_(beta) is upper triangular.But,[T]*_(beta)=[T*]_(beta)=[T]_(beta).So,[T*]_(beta) & [T]_(beta) are both upper triangular,and hence,[T]_(beta ) is a diagonal matrix. thus $\ beta $ mus consist of eigenvectors of T.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake that may be but then the OP should have simply stated as much. The way the question was asked just seems a lot like how many people ask their homework problems. More detail about the context of a question is generally always better.

Comment: @K.Power:Thanks for advice,I'll take care next time.Actually,i'dont know much about how to use this site.

Comment: @K.Power It is true that many simply post their homework, but before we pass-harsh-judgement, we should first look more closely and seriously at the problem posted. It should have been obvious that this was not a mere homework question.(Simple familiarity with the Spectral Theorem would suffice to convey that much..)

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake I see now that that is the case, and so I do apologize to PK Styles. In future the he\she will know now to just add an extra sentence of explanation of the context so as to prevent tired people like me from jumping to conclusions without actually engaging the old brain.

Answer (score 1):

This is referred to as the Second Spectral theorem. For a complete proof of both the first and second, look [here](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~helena/teaching/math108b/handouts/notes_spectral_theorems.pdf). I will simply post the part that interests you here as an answer and since you are familiar with the first part and Schur's Theorem you should be able to follow the proof. Of course, in the link provided, the treatment of the subject is complete.

> Assume $F = \Bbb{R}$ and $T$ is a self-adjoint linear operator on
>   $V$ . 
>   
> Then, the characteristic polynomial of $T$ splits, and Schur’s theorem implies that there
>   exists an orthonormal basis $β$ for $V$ such that $A = [T]_β$ is upper-triangular. 
>   
> The same proof
>   as for the first spectral theorem now works since $T$ is normal, but it is easier to note that
>   since $T^∗=T$, we know that both $A$ and $A^T = A^∗ = A$ are upper triangular. Therefore, $A$
>   is diagonal.